# Linking CSS from the same directory in Django

Tags: html, django-templates

I learned that common practice in django is, to put your css files into the static folder, although it should be possible to link them with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` too, when stored in together with the html in templates.

.../templates/newyear/ both html and css stored here.

For a short test I just linked the css like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Is it Newyear?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if newyear  %}
      <h1>YES</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>NO</h1>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

But it IS NOT applied when I run the page with django. If i open the SAME html file with my browser, the css IS applied. No file locations or code changed.

When i run (css now stored in static):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Is it Newyear?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'newyear/styles.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if newyear  %}
      <h1>YES</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>NO</h1>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

with django, the css IS applied. Is it possible to link a stylesheet with`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'newyear/styles.css' %}">` in django or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to link a stylesheet with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'newyear/styles.css' %}">` in django or not?

Yes, that is possible and you've done it yourself. This is the django way to do it.

> Is it possible to link a stylesheet with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` in django or not?

This is partially possible. 
When you open the html file with your browser **not** via django it works, because it is looking for a linked file within the same directory called 'styles.css'. So why does it not work for django? When running your django project in production or via the development server, a server deliveres the static files. So in this case the html file requests 'styles.css' to the server. This url is most likely not set up, therefore no CSS is linked. If you had configured your server to deliver to that request it would work though.

As a learning experience you should check what the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'newyear/styles.css' %}">`-representation actually translates to in raw html. If you want to hardcode the CSS links, that is what you want to write there instead of just `href="styles.css"`. Using the `static` keyword makes django resolve this to the correct URL based on your `STATIC_URL` setting and the location of your static files.

**TL;DR:** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` only works if you are not relying on django's static files handling.

Comment: I looked at the raw html, and I'm even more confused. At first glance `href="/static/newyear/styles.css"` made sense to me, but this path works, even after I store the css in templates/newyear/styles.css. On the other hand when I store the file there instead of the static folder, `href="/templates/newyear/styles.css"` doesn't work...

Comment: Remember to always hard reload your site because of browser-caching. Watch the output of the development server, from where it pulls the CSS. I recommend sticking to the django conventions regardless of what else works. You'll be happier during actual deployment then.